# How to benchmark individual layers in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

To my knowledge, there are a couple of different benchmarking tools for TensorFlow, such as the [TensorFlow Model Benchmark Tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark) and [PerfZero](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/perfzero).

However, these tools seem to benchmark model performance as a whole. Are there any tools that allow you to benchmark or time individual layers of a neural network during training of the whole NN? I'm working on a research project where we need to benchmark the performance of individual layers, so a tool like this would be very helpful.

Thanks!